# What are other CDK templates besides sample-app?

Tags: aws-cdk

As I am learning the AWS CDK I have invoked 'cdk init' to create a new project with the default sample-app template.  What are other templates and/or where are they located?

```
 $ cdk init --help
 cdk init [TEMPLATE]

 Create a new, empty CDK project from a template. Invoked without TEMPLATE, the app template will be used.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the other templates on [CDK GitHub source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/init-templates).

**Usage:**

```
cdk init --language LANGUAGE [TEMPLATE]
```

**Where:**

> **LANGUAGE**:
>   is one of the supported programming languages: csharp (C#),
>   java (Java), javascript (JavaScript), python (Python), or typescript
>   (TypeScript)
>
> **TEMPLATE**:  is an optional template. If the desired template is **app**, the
>   default, you may omit it.

Available templates: `app \ lib \ sample-app`

Comment: Seems like a bit of an oversight in the docs that's there's no list of available templates (and description of what they're for!).

Answer (score 15):

`cdk init --list` can be used to view a list of the available templates

Comment: Nice, this command added after I answered my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As of now there are only 3 templates available
Available templates:

- app: Template for a CDK Application
  └─ cdk init app --language=[csharp|fsharp|go|java|javascript|python|typescript]
- lib: Template for a CDK Construct Library
  └─ cdk init lib --language=typescript
- sample-app: Example CDK Application with some constructs
  └─ cdk init sample-app --language=[csharp|fsharp|go|java|javascript|python|typescript]